# How to omit lambda parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

Sometimes I don't use all lambda parameters, like the second parameter in the example below, which is an old value in a change event:

```
selected.onChange { value, _ ->
    checkBox.isChecked = value
}
```

How do I omit them? Cause that clutters the code and hurts readability. Previously I used the method above, but in kotlin 1.0.0-beta-1103 underscores are reserved.

Comment: If you use the lambda often enough to warrant this, you could always add an extension function that does the same thing with the parameters you don't want removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of 1.1, you can do exactly that:

> Underscore for unused variables (since 1.1)
>
> If the lambda parameter is unused, you can place an underscore instead
>   of its name:
>
> ```
> map.forEach { _, value -> println("$value!") }
> ```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11

I should add that the compiler now generates a warning for unused lambda parameters, and there's a new corresponding quick fix for Android Studio

Answer (score 5):

You can use [escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin) (i.e. backticks) or overload `onChange`.

**Backticks**

```
selected.onChange { value, `_` ->
    checkBox.isChecked = value
}
```

**Overload `onChange`**

```
interface Listener<T1, T2> {
    fun onChange(f: (T1, T2) -> Unit) // original method
    fun onChange(f: (T1) -> Unit)     // new method
}
```

And if you cannot change `Listener<T1, T2>` (or whatever type `settable` is from your example) then you can use an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions):

```
fun <T1, T2> Listener<T1, T2>.onChange(f: (T1) -> Unit) = onChange { t1, t2 -> f(t1) }
```

You can then call `onChange` like you want:

```
selected.onChange { value ->
    checkBox.isChecked = value
}
```